# 2d rendering stutter

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce-experience

In any game that uses 2-dimensional rendering, (not necessarily a 2d-based game), I find that there is a consistent stutter happening approximately twice a second ONLY affecting the 2d part. Sometimes the stutter slows down the animation for a frame, and sometimes it jumps ahead a frame. Because of the forward-jumping, I suspect it is not a problem with my GPU being overloaded, but might have something to do with over/underclocking. I have tried resetting my graphics card,  but nothing changed.

GPU: GeForce GTX 950

CPU: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor 3.50 GHz

Installed RAM: 16GB

Monitor: 60Hz 1920x1080p

Comment: If you're using your video card beyond the specs, try resetting it back to factory defaults, and try again.  That could eliminate your video card from the problems.

Comment: I have never touched my video card or any settings for it in the bios, but ill try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/).

Geforce Experience is known to sometimes mess up driver installation.

If that fails, then reset any overclocks you have, as @Frank said.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Before i try DDU though, how would i reinstall my graphics driver after it is uninstalled? Should i just try again with geforce?

Comment: Download it from the nvidia website

Comment: Problem Solved! For some reason I had my v-sync set off.